# Find eigenvalues for a basic equation

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I have to check if I can get the eigenvalues for a specific equation. Actually I just want the first 2 beta:

```
eqy = Y''[y] + \[Beta]^2*Y[y] == 0;
```

So I've tried to write the boundary conditions and the DSolve:

```
ic1 = Y'[y] == 0 /. y -> 0;
ic2 = Y'[y] == 0 /. y -> 0.5;
sol = DSolve[{eqy}, ic1, ic2, Y[y], {y, 0, 0.5}]
```

Unlikely this results in "Y'[0]==0 cannot be used as a function. I don't know how to solve it.
The result should be:
[image]

with the following as (22) and (23). Psi is a function with separable variables: Psi=X(x)*Y(y)*G(t).
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, it should read: ?`sol = DSolve[{eqy, ic1, ic2}, Y[y], {y, 0, 0.5}]`

Comment: I'm very sorry! I made such a stupid mistake. Thank you so much!!!